# Remove items from multiple nested list using linq

Tags: c#

I am having nested list items `ParticipantsDetails` & `AssigneeDetails` inside parent list `TransactionHistoryDetails`.

Both of nested list contains `Name` Property and I would like to remove items which contain `Name` as `null`

Code:

```
transactionHistory.TransactionHistoryDetails.ForEach(u => u.ParticipantsDetails.RemoveAll(a => a.Name == null));

transactionHistory.TransactionHistoryDetails.ForEach(u => u.AssigneeDetails.RemoveAll(a => a.Name == null));
```

This code works! But is there any way I can achieve the same in a single line by using `||` operator?

Comment: Don't you like the () => { **code** } approach? This way you can do everything in the same foreach, but two lines inside the brackets body

Comment: Why do you want it in a single line?  You'd likely end up with an even more complex line that would be confusing for another developer to understand what it is doing.  It is okay to be more verbose if it improves readability.

Comment: I see no LINQ in that code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot achieve this in a single line, because your two calls of `RemoveAll` operate on two separate collections. You can combine the two lambdas into a single one, like this:

```
transactionHistory.TransactionHistoryDetails.ForEach(u => {
    u.ParticipantsDetails.RemoveAll(a => a.Name == null);
    u.AssigneeDetails.RemoveAll(a => a.Name == null);
});
```

**Note:** There are alternative approaches to this. For example, you can introduce a method on `TransactionHistoryDetails` to "sanitize" both lists, essentially hiding two `RemoveAll` lines from sight.